# Why does strptime from Time::Piece not parse my format?

Tags: perl, datetime, parsing, strptime

My collegue (who has left the company) has written a bunch of scripts, including batch and Perl scripts, and I'm getting rid of the regional settings dependencies.

In the last Perl script, he's written the following piece of code:

```
my $format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M";
my $today_converted = Time::Piece->strptime($today, $format) - ONE_HOUR - ONE_HOUR - ONE_HOUR - ONE_HOUR - ONE_HOUR;
```

(the idea is to get five hours before midnight of that particular date)

The value of `$today` seems to be "03/04/2017" (which stands for the third of April (European dateformat)), which seems not to be understood by Time::Piece implementation:

```
Error parsing time at C:/Perl64/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 481.
```

Which format can I use which is understood by Time::Piece Perl implementation?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a "European date format". While `dd/mm/yyyy` is probably the most common, germanic countries generally use dots (`dd.mm.yyyy`) instead, as in the given `$format`.

Comment: Why subtract the five hours individually? What's wrong with `5 * ONE_HOUR`?

Comment: By "European date format", I think you mean "[date format used in most of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)" :-)

Comment: By European date format, I mean first the day and then the month (American formats tend to put the month before), hence "03/04/2017" means "third of April" and not "Fourth of March". I'm sorry but I have no clue on date formats in other continents :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the format you have dots `.` as the date delimiter, but in the data you have slashes `/`. That's why it doesn't parse. It needs an exact match.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really well awake :-)

Comment: @Dominique don't worry about it. I'll edit your title so it is actually valid and retract my close-vote for typo. I've run into this myself a couple of times, and I think it makes sense to keep this around.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth clarifying that `strptime()` will parse most date and time formats - that's the point of the method. But you need to define the format of the date string that you are parsing. That's what the second parameter to `strptime()` (in this case, your `$format` variable) is for.

The letters used in the format are taken from a standard list of definitions which used by every implementation of `strptime()` (and its inverse, `strftime()`). See `man strptime` on your system for a complete list of the available options.

In your case, the format is `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M` - which means that it will parse timestamps which have the day, month and year separated by dots, followed by a space and the hours and minutes separated by a colon. If you want to parse timestamps in a different format, then you will need to change the definition of `$format`.